# What pathway triggers loss of appetite resulting from vomiting/nausea?

Tags: nutrition, obesity, nausea, anorexia, food-addiction

Some anorexic/bulimic people purposely induce auto vomiting which results in significant periods of no appetite, no food craving, and no hunger. There obviously is a purposeful mechanism in autonomy that triggers this effect. Does anyone know specifically what it is? Would probably solve the world obesity epidemic if there was a way to emulate this mechanism in pill form which would cause people to loose hunger and food cravings.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: So your question is "can we induce nausea?" To which the answer is yes. Appetite suppressants also exist, as prior research should have told you.